# For loop returns NA's: return only the first match of ifelse statement

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

How can I make my for loop return only the first match of an ifelse statement?

Here is my data frame:

```
df <- structure(
  list(
x0 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
       "0", "0"),
x1 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
       "0"),
x2 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
x3 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"),
x4 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", NA, "0", "0", "0", NA, "0"),
x5 = c("0",
       "0", "0", "0", NA, "0", "0", "0", NA, "0"),
x6 = c("0", "0",
       "0", "0", NA, "0", "0", "0", NA, "0"),
x7 = c("0", "0", "0",
       "0", NA, "0", "0", "0", NA, "0"),
x8 = c("0", "0", "0", "0",
       NA, "0", "0", "0", NA, "0"),
x9 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", NA,
       "0", "0", "0", NA, "1"),
x10 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", NA,
        "0", "0", "1", NA, "1"),
x11 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", NA,
        "0", "0", "1", NA, "2"),
x12 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", NA,
        "0", "0", "0", NA, "2"),
x13 = c("0", "0", "0", "0", NA,
        "0", "0", "1", NA, "3"),
x14 = c(NA, NA, "0", "0", NA, NA,
        NA, "2", NA, NA),
x15 = c(
  NA_character_,
  NA_character_,
  NA_character_,
  NA_character_,
  NA_character_,
  NA_character_,
  NA_character_,
  NA_character_,
  NA_character_,
  NA_character_
)
  ),
  .Names = c(
"x0",
"x1",
"x2",
"x3",
"x4",
"x5",
"x6",
"x7",
"x8",
"x9",
"x10",
"x11",
"x12",
"x13",
"x14",
"x15"
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, 10L),
  class = "data.frame"
)
```

and here is what the expected output that I would like to achieve:

```
df$expectedoutput <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 'x14', NA, 'x11')
```

and here is my attempt to obtain the said output:

```
df$newvar <- NA
for (i in 1:16) {
   df$newvar <- ifelse(df[,i] == "2" & is.na(df$newvar), 
                                  colnames(df[i]), NA)
}
```

I believe that my problem is that the for loop that I've created goes on to the end and overwrites the first match that occurs, e.g. for row 10, instead of finishing on the column name for `df[10,12]` the loop continues to `df[10,16]` and therefore returns an `NA` However, I could be wrong and perhaps this isn't my problem.

Comment: You are rewriting `df$newvar` every time through the loop, only the last one will be there when it ends.

Comment: Yes I know @RuiBarradas this is the problem for which I have asked for a solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use `apply` to get the column index of the first 2.
Next, get the name corresponding to that index

```
first2 <- apply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) head(which(x == 2), 1))
df$newvar <- 
  vapply(first2, 
         FUN = function(x) if (length(x)) names(df)[x] else NA_character_, 
         character(1))
```

The `for` loop equivalent would be

```
df$newvar <- NA
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
  first2 <- head(which(df[i, ] == 2), 1)
  df$newvar[i] <- if (length(first2)) names(df)[first2] else NA
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure that for loop equivalent generalizes to dataframes of other dimensions, but the apply method does.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't.  `i` iterates over the rows. `first2` is redefined for each row, and is either length 1 or 0. `df$newvar[i]` gets updated based on `first2`. So the only dimension that is ever referenced is the row.  If it doesn't generalize, it's a nuance I can't see.

Comment: Yeah I think I overlooked something